# Problema em laço for

Tags: c, for, iterator

Estou com um problema e não estou conseguindo identifica-lo no meu código, tenho um for com 60 iterações, e ele está caindo nos if's quando o identificar (i neste caso) for divisível por 5 ou por 3 somente na primeira iteração, quando i é 0. Após isso ele passa as outras até final sem parar nos if's.

```
int main(){

int i,j,opcao,qtd_taxi,qtd_passageiro,tamFilaTaxi=0,tamFilaPassageiro=0;
char id_a_inserir[3];

Fila* taxis = criar_fila();
Fila* passageiros = criar_fila();

for(i=0;i<60;i++){
    printf("-- Minuto %d -- \n",i);
    if(i%5==0){
        while(qtd_taxi<0 || qtd_taxi>5){
            printf("Digite a quantidade de carros: \n");
            scanf("%d",&qtd_taxi);
            fflush(stdin);
            if(qtd_taxi>=0 && qtd_taxi<=5){
                for(j=0;j<qtd_taxi;j++){
                    tamFilaTaxi ++;
                    sprintf(id_a_inserir, "t%d", tamFilaTaxi);
                    inserir(taxis,id_a_inserir);
                }
            }else printf(" *Quantidade invalida! \n \n");
        }
        qtd_taxi=0;
    }
    if(i%3==0){
        while(qtd_passageiro<0 || qtd_passageiro>3){
            printf("Digite a quantidade de passageiros: \n");
            scanf("%d",&qtd_passageiro);
            fflush(stdin);
            if(qtd_passageiro>=0 && qtd_passageiro<=3){
                for(j=0;j<qtd_passageiro;j++){
                    tamFilaPassageiro ++;
                    sprintf(id_a_inserir, "p%d", tamFilaPassageiro);
                    inserir(passageiros,id_a_inserir);
                }
            }else printf(" *Quantidade invalida! \n \n");
        }
        qtd_passageiro=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: seus `if` parecem ok, mas você não está inicializando as variáveis que utiliza no `while`... pode ser ai o problema, porque depois que entra a primeira vez tu abriu pra `0` e ai nunca mais entra.

Comment: na verdade ele cai nos if logo na primeira iteração, depois passa todas as outras sem acontecer nada.

Comment: mas pensa comigo, depois que entro a primeira vez você atribui valor 0 pras variáveis que utiliza no `while` logo nunca mais o `while` vai entrar

Comment: mas tenho que zerar elas depois de cada operação, como posso proceder então?

Comment: qual o objetivo do if?

Comment: quando ele entra no `if%5` você quer adicionar carros até que ele digite um valor diferente de 0-5?

Comment: experimentar trocar seu `while` por `do.. while` :)

Comment: o for esta representando uma hora(60 min), e a cada 5 minutos ele deve incluir carros em uma lista (1º if), e a cada 3 minutos ele deve incluir passageiros em outra lista (2º if), Usei o resto da divisão para saber quando realizar cada operação. Ex: cada 3 minutos, vai de 0,3,6,9. Então se for divisível por 3, cai no if.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25336/discussion-between-mathi901-and-maicon-carraro).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como expliquei nos comentários, a primeira vez sempre vai entrar e depois você está atribuindo `0` a variável que utiliza no controle do `while` então sempre vai dar `false` e nunca vai entrar. Para obrigar a entrar pelo menos uma vez pode utilizar o `do ... while`

```
for(i=0;i<60;i++){
    printf("-- Minuto %d -- \n",i);
    if(i%5==0){
        do {
            printf("Digite a quantidade de carros: \n");
            scanf("%d",&qtd_taxi);
            // ... restante
        } while(qtd_taxi<0 || qtd_taxi>5);
        qtd_taxi=0;
    }
    if(i%3==0){
        do {
            printf("Digite a quantidade de passageiros: \n");
            scanf("%d",&qtd_passageiro);
            // restante do código
        } while(qtd_passageiro<0 || qtd_passageiro>3);
        qtd_passageiro=0;
    }
}
```