# Qual é a utilidade e importância de "do... while"?

Tags: algoritmo, loop, característica-linguagem, while, do-while

O comando `while` é uma estrutura de repetição com uma condição no início da declaração.

Exemplo:

```
while (condição) {
    sentenças a executar
}
```

Já `do...while` possui verificação no final, ou seja, o código da estrutura de repetição é executado pelo menos uma vez.

Exemplo:

```
do {
    sentenças do loop
} while (condição)
```

Poderíamos implementar `do...while` utilizando um loop `while`. Neste caso, a parte do código que seria executada, pelo menos um vez, viria acima do `while`, seguindo a estrutura lógica sequencial do código.

Existem situação onde só podemos utilizar `do...while`?

Qual é a utilidade e importância de  `do...while` ?

Comment: Não deixe de ler esta excelente resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/81431

Comment: No Visual Basic, o `Do...While` é chamado de `Do...Until` :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Em nenhuma situação precisamos realmente do `do ... while` a não ser para deixar o código mais elegante e expressar melhor a intenção de que a execução do bloco deve ocorrer pelo menos uma vez antes de decidir se ele se repetirá ou não.

Sempre é possível fazer o mesmo só com o `while`. Claro que o código poderá ter que ser um pouco maior e menos elegante, ter que fazer algo artificial para garantir que a primeira execução da condição seja verdadeira.

Nem sempre isto pode ser tão fácil de fazer porque pode envolver a verificação de algo que possui [efeitos colaterais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/330341/101), em alguns casos até ter algo semelhante ao [paradoxo do Gato de Schrödinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat), onde para acessar um valor, você muda o valor. Pode dar resultados diferentes dependendo do momento. Dá para resolver isto, mas tem que saber fazer, lembrar de fazer e aumenta o código. Em geral a solução é uma *flag* ou um valor em cache, que pode ficar complexo quando o acesso muda o valor (ainda que isto não deveria acontecer em bons códigos).

Claro que pode ajudar a não cometer erros também. Pode ser que se engane para garantir que a primeira passada dê verdadeiro e em algum caso fora do comum dê falso, ou pode mudar algo no código que acabe mudando a situação de garantia de verdadeiro sem que o programador perceba.

Ele dá mais legibilidade e manutenibilidade como toda construção que ajuda dar mais semântica ao intuito.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

> Já do...while possui verificação no final, ou seja, o código da
>   estrutura de repetição é executado pelo menos um vez.

Você mesmo respondeu. O do...while existe quando queremos executar o código que está dentro da estrutura de repetição pelo menos uma vez sem passar pelo teste lógico. Existem situações em que isso é útil, embora não seja tão frequente.

> Poderíamos implementar do..while utilizando um loop while. Neste caso,
>   a parte do código que seria executada, pelo menos um vez, viria acima
>   do while, seguindo a estrutura lógica sequencial do código.

Sim, seria uma maneira de ter a funcionalidade do do...while sem utilizá-lo. Entretanto, note que haverá repetição de código. Se o pedaço de código que estiver dentro do loop for grande, então você terá uma significativa repetição de código, o que obviamente não é bom.

Answer (score 4):

Tudo depende da sua lógica de fazer as coisas. Pode dar uma olhada na solução que coloquei aqui: [Problema em laço for](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71906/problema-em-la%C3%A7o-for/71915#71915)

Nesta situação ele utilizava a mesma variável do input para a condição do `while`, a única saída dele sem usar `do... while` era colocar um valor arbitrário que não caísse no laço na primeira vez ou então criar uma `flag`.

Novamente, tudo depende de como você programa.