# Por que usar do "while (0)"?

Tags: c, c++, while, macro

No código do Linux vi algumas macros com:

```
do
{

}while(0)
```

Existe motivo? Porque aparentemente não tem lógica um laço de repetição em que o código repete apenas uma vez.

Comment: Essa pergunta no SOen é identica:[Why while(0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for)

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78493/qual-%C3%A9-a-utilidade-e-import%C3%A2ncia-de-do-while

Comment: Esse não é o while infinito. O teste sempre dará falso. Por isso é um do..while, se não fosse, nem entraria. Pra infinito deveria ser while(1).

Comment: Normalmente omite-se o `;` no fim da macro; esse `;` vem do codigo propriamente dito.

Comment: Cara, vejo todo mundo questionando isso! O que tem a ver pergunta estar no SOen? Nem todo mundo sabe ler inglês :)

Comment: É para efeito de declaração de macro.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Não existe provavelmente porque é pouco necessário e dá para resolver desta forma. De qualquer forma esta construção é usado essencialmente em macros (acho que você já sabia disto pelas *tags* originais da pergunta).

Ele serve para agrupar vários comandos sem causar erros quando o pré-processador expande o código.

Exemplo:

```
#define MACRO(x) do { funcao(x); x++; } while (0)
```

Pode ser usado em:

```
if (a > 0)
    MACRO(a);
else
    a++;
```

Isto causaria erro no mesmo uso:

```
#define MACRO(x) { funcao(x); x++; }
```

Porque seria expandido para:

```
if (a > 0)
    { funcao(x); x++; };
else
    a++;
```

Funcionaria se você não tivesse usado o ponto e vírgula na linha da macro, mas ninguém faz isto. E seria um erro obrigar o programador saber que esta macro deve ser usada assim.

Isto é pior ainda:

```
#define MACRO(x) funcao(x); x++
```

Expandiria para:

```
if (a > 0)
    funcao(x); x++;
else
    a++;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/Macro2.c).

Obviamente destruiria o uso do `if` como se imaginava e o `else` ficaria solto, gerando um erro de sintaxe.

Em alguns casos é possível usar isto em código normal, mas é raro ser útil e legível.

Comment: Além do que o Manero falou, tem também a questão do controle de fluxo com "continue" e "break" que requer escopos como o do "do/while". Não sei se essas macros usam para isso, mas serve para controlar mais livremente. Pode, por exemplo, definir condicionais onde se repete o loop e então botar "continue", bem como pode-se mudar a condição do loop para 1 ou true (C++) e definir condicionais onde o loop cessa usando "break.

Answer (score 7):

É também uma forma de se evitar if's extremamente agrupados e simplificar a verificação de erros:

```
do {
  // faça algo
  if (error) {
    break;
  }
  // faça alguma outra coisa
  if (error) {
    break;
  }
  // etc..
} while (0);
```

Comment: Resumindo em poucas palavras: se tiver break neste bloco do ... while(0), é um "goto" disfarçado.

Comment: @epx exatamente, é a construção de estruturas complicadas só para dizer que não usou `goto`: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101