# Por que não é muito comum o uso de do/while?

Tags: while, do-while

Não sei se isso ocorre somente em *PHP*, mas percebo que não é muito comum o uso de `do/while` nos códigos escritos nele.

Exemplo:

```
while (ob_get_level() > 0) {
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

Que (creio eu) poderia ser feito assim

```
do {

   ob_end_clean();

} while(ob_get_level() > 0);
```

Por que o uso de `while` é mais comum do que `do/while`?

Poderíamos afirmar que `do/while` não tem tanta utilidade?

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual é a utilidade e importância de “do… while”?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78493/91)

Comment: Primeiro eu achei que poderia ser baseada em opiniões, mas resolvi responder objetivamente ignorando o que poderia insinuar opinião, o que não correu com as demais respostas. Agora estou pensando em duplicata, lembrava da pergunta mas não lembrava que a resposta era a mesma.

Comment: Se for pensar por esse lado "Por que não é usado" e "Qual é a utilidade" poderia remeter à mesma resposta. Se acharem que devem marcar como duplicada, eu mesmo voto a favor :)

Comment: A questão é diferente, mas as respostas poderão ir para o mesmo rumo. Isso é um problema?

Comment: Se a pergunta não for fechada, eu gostaria de tentar responder baseado em [métodos formais](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todos_formais) - eu *suspeito* (mas ainda não posso dizer com certeza) que é mais fácil entender a semântica de um código que executa zero ou mais vezes do que um que executa uma ou mais vezes.

Comment: Pode responder @mgibsonbr :). Não há nada que impeça

Comment: Tem essa outra, [Por que usar do while(0)?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80669/91) que já é um contexto diferente.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Haha é que eu sabia que uma resposta dessas ia demorar um pouco, e eu vi o pessoal falando em fechar, se eu não me manifestasse logo e isso acontecesse, quando acabasse de formular a resposta não poderia mais postar... :P

Comment: que isso @mgibsonbr! acho que só estavam esperando você para poder fechar a conta!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Talvez porque seja mais simples determinar a **invariante** do loop através do `while` (e do `for`) do que do `do..while`. E a invariante é algo que é sempre necessário para se entender a semântica do código, esteja ele colocado de forma explícita ou implícita (i.e. só na cabeça do programador).

### Invariante

Todo código [imperativo] possui um conjunto de variáveis que progride do estado `E0` pro `E1`, pro `E2`, etc, até chegar no estado final `En`. Tipicamente, o estado é afetado por cada instrução única, e pode-se sumarizar seu conjunto de valores antes e depois de cada instrução:

```
{}
x = 10;
{ x = 10 }
y = 20;
{ x = 10, y = 20 }
z = 2*x + y;
{ x = 10, y = 20, z = 40 }
x = 30;
{ x = 30, y = 20, z = 40 }
...
```

Quando se inclui loops, no entanto, não é possível se estabelecer os valores exatos das variáveis, pois cada instrução pode executar diversas vezes e o estado será diferente entre uma e outra:

```
{}
a = 3;
{ a = 3 }
b = 5;
{ a = 3, b = 5 }
r = 0;
{ a = 3, b = 5, r = 0 }

while ( a > 0 ):
    { a = ?, b = 5, r = ? }
    r += b;
    { a = ?, b = 5, r = ? }
    a--;
    { a = ?, b = 5, r = ? }

{ a <= 0, b = 5, r = ? }
return r;
```

Para entender o estado ao final da execução (implicitamente, todo mundo deve ter percebido que `r` conterá o produto `a * b`, certo?), se usa a técnica do invariante: estabeleça uma condição que deve ser verdadeira **antes** e **depois** do loop executar:

```
{ r = (3-a)*b }
```

Verifique que de fato ela é verdadeira antes:

```
{ a = 3, b = 5, r = 0, r = (3-a)*b = (3-3)*5 = 0 } OK
```

E que, se ela for verdadeira depois, ela conterá o resultado desejado:

```
{ a = 0, b = 5, r = (3-a)*b = (3-0)*5 = 3*5 } OK*
```

Por fim, verifique se - a cada execução do loop - o invariante começa verdadeiro e termina verdadeiro:

```
{ a = a0, b = 5, r = (3-a)*b = (3-a0)*b } OK, Premissa
r += b;
{ a = a0, b = 5, r = (3-a0)*b + b } X
a--;
{ a = a0-1, b = 5, r = (3-a0)*b + b = (3-a0+1)*b = (3-(a0-1))*b = (3-a)*b } OK
```

Assim temos a prova de que o código acima realmente produzirá o resultado esperado.

* Nota: faltou aqui provar que, partindo de um `a` inteiro positivo, ele sairá do loop como zero, e não como qualquer número menor que zero. Como o corpo do loop decrementa `a` apenas uma vez, não tem como ele ficar negativo, mas infelizmente não sei como formalizar isso...

### Aplicando ao `while` e ao `do..while`

A técnica de análise descrita acima é um tipo de [método formal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todos_formais), mas ainda que tal formalismo seja raramente usado na prática, ao menos na cabeça do programador uma análise semelhante é feita, pra entender *por que* ao final de um loop o programa estará num estado que corresponda ao resultado da computação desejada. Muitos bugs são decorrência da pessoa não perceber que tal condição que se supunha ser verdadeira durante e após um loop na verdade não é (levando ao processo tedioso de depurar o loop passo a passo no *debugger*, ou talvez imprimindo valores de variáveis na tela conforma o loop avança).

Num programa bem estruturado a função de cada variável é clara, o progresso dos estados é simples e homogêneo, e ainda que o invariante não esteja formalizado o programador consegue perceber que algo "se mantém" entre uma execução do loop e outra. Mas e quanto ao `do..while`, esse mesmo raciocínio não se aplicaria?

O problema do `do..while` é que - como apontado nas demais respostas - ele surge em situações em que é **obrigatório** que o corpo do laço execute ao menos uma vez. Por que é obrigatório? Normalmente porque tem alguma variável que não foi inicializada direito, um valor que pode ou não ser nulo, etc. Porque se nada disso fosse verdade, se o estado do programa fosse perfeitamente válido mesmo se o loop não executasse nenhuma vez, não haveria a necessidade do `do..while`.

Sendo assim, a análise de um código que usa `do..while` é mais trabalhosa do que um que não usa. Pois a princípio, *na primeira iteração do loop* o invariante ainda não é necessariamente verdadeiro, enquanto em todas as seguintes ele precisa ser. Consequentemente, é necessário escrever um corpo que simultaneamente: 1) leve o programa de um estado em que o invariante é falso para um que o invariante é verdadeiro; 2) **com as mesmas instruções**, parte de um estado em que o invariante vale para outro que ele continue valendo. Isso é complicado, e acaba exigindo que se pense em cada linha de código duas vezes (na primeira iteração vai acontecer isso, nas outras vai acontecer aquilo), inclusive com a possibilidade de se introduzir `if`s para tratar de modo diferenciado da primeira iteração e das demais.

### `break`, `continue`, `return` etc.

Incidentalmente, esse mesmo problema ocorre quando um loop é interrompido "abruptamente" no meio da sua execução (via `break`, `continue`, `return`) ou mesmo quando uma função se encerra prematuramente. Certamente você já deve ter visto algum "conselho" sugerindo evitar essas construções, da mesma forma como todo mundo já foi advertido em relação ao [`goto`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/215). Quebras de fluxo mascaram/invalidam o invariante...

Minha conclusão, no entanto, é a mesma que nos demais casos: use `do..while` quando fizer sentido, mas certifique-se de que compreende bem a progressão de estados entre uma iteração e outra, e se guarde contra qualquer possibilidade de deixar seu programa num estado indefinido. Na minha experiência pessoal, isso muitas vezes implica em refatorar o código, o que acaba muitas vezes me levando a - veja só - substituir o `do..while` por um `while`! Isso já aconteceu tantas vezes que, ao projetar um código novo, já começo por prestar atenção a determinados padrões, mover código "especial" para fora do loop, e a consequência natural é cair numa situação em que o `while` é o laço mais adequado ao meu caso.

(Por fim, um adendo: muitas vezes a única função de um loop é iterar sobre uma coleção, caso em que há construções mais apropriadas para isso do que um loop - `foreach`, `map`, etc, em particular porque simplificam o caso especial da coleção estar vazia; em outras, o loop trabalha de forma muito próxima com um índice ou contador, de modo que é mais fácil controlar o número mínimo de iterações através das condições envolvendo o índice do que via uma estrutura de loop diferente; o único caso em que um `do..while` me parece natural - e esse caso é raro - é quando a lógica do seu código é "tente fazer algo, e se não der certo tente de novo", uma típica aplicação de *polling* por exemplo, algo cada vez mais raro nos dias de hoje...)

Comment: Cadê o emoticon do aplauso aqui? Já me aconteceu várias vezes isso de começar com um `do..while`, feliz por ter esta opção, e depois acabar substituindo-o pelo `while`. Faltava entender por quê e agora eu tenho uma idéia e material para pensar.

Answer (score 8):

As duas construções são completamente diferentes, elas não fazem a mesma coisa. Então isto provavelmente explica porque um é mais usado que outro. Provavelmente a segunda forma é menos necessária que a primeira.

A primeira executará **zero** ou mais vezes. A segunda executará **uma** ou mais vezes, dependendo da condição, claro. Mas a segunda garante uma execução do bloco enquanto que a primeira pode não executar nada.

Você pode dizer que em alguma situação específica dentro de um contexto maior da aplicação você pode garantir que a primeira construção executará pelo menos uma vez, mas aí é algo dependente do contexto.

A semântica da segunda é clara que **deve obrigatoriamente** executar uma vez, sem depender de nada. Mesmo que você possa ter certeza que a primeira executará uma vez em determinado contexto, isso pode mudar no futuro porque a semântica dela é permitir que nenhuma execução ocorrerá.

Sempre entenda o problema e escreva a construção que expressa a real necessidade do código, mesmo que, por coincidência, uma outra construção possa funcionar naquele contexto.

Answer (score 4):

O `do/while` garante que o bloco de código seja executado ao menos uma vez.

No caso do `while`, uma condição é testada antes do bloco de código ser executado.

Embora sejam diferentes, eu arrisco dizer que o `while` é mais utilizado simplesmente por facilitar a leitura. Enquanto no `do/while` você vai precisar descer no código para entender qual a condição que aquele código no bloco está obedecendo, no `while` você enxerga isto imediatamente. Acredito que seja mais natural para o desenvolvedor.