# Qual a diferença da estrutura "enquanto" e repita no VisualG?

Tags: loop, while, visualg, portugol, do-while

Qual a diferença da estrutura "enquanto" e repita no VisualG? Tem como exemplificar?

Comment: Uma será executada **enquanto** a condição for verdadeira. A outra, será repetida **até que** a condição se torne verdadeira.

Comment: Resposta simples,porem tirou as duvidas que eu tinha.Obgd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A principal é que a condição do `enquanto` é avaliada logo na sua entrada, portanto pode nem executar nada do laço se a condição já for falsa, enquanto (desculpe o trocadilho :) ), que a condição do `repita` só é avaliada pela primeira vez ao final da primeira execução do bloco.

Também é diferente porque `enquanto` continha enquanto (sem trocadilho) a condição for verdadeira, e no `repita` ele repete até alcançar aquela condição, portanto repete enquanto a condição for falsa.

```
var i: inteiro
inicio
i <- 0
enquanto i < 10 faca
   escreva(i)
   i <- i + 1
fimenquanto

var i: inteiro
inicio
i <- 0
repita
   escreva(i)
   i <- i + 1
ate i >= 10
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/EnquantoRepita.ptg).

Veja [Qual é a utilidade e importância de "do... while"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78493/101). O `do-while` é um misto dos dois. Ele sempre deixa executar uma vez, ma a condição de saída é o falso, igual é no `while`. Na prática poucas linguagens, nenhuma fortemente *mainstream* usa uma construção equivalente ao `repita`.

Comment: Da para se fazer as mesmas funções do "repita" com a estrutura "enquanto"?

Comment: Até dá para fazer sempre a mesma coisa, mas nem sempre é o jeito mais conveniente, por isso existem as duas formas.

Comment: @Arthur Dê uma olhada no [tour], além de aceitar respostas, você pode votar em tudo o que achar útil no site todo.