# Laço de repetição em C

Tags: c, loop, while, do-while

Olá, sou iniciante em programação e tenho uma pergunta: estou fazendo um programa que tem um menu e um cadastro a ser realizado pelo usuário. Gostaria de saber como faz para o menu do programa aparecer sempre depois que finalizar o cadastro, em vez de finalizar o programa. Irei utilizar o *while* ou *do while*?

Comment: Linha de comando?

Comment: Sim, preciso que essa linhas de comando apareça sempre depois de encerrar o cadastro

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual é a utilidade e importância de "do... while"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78493/qual-%c3%a9-a-utilidade-e-import%c3%a2ncia-de-do-while)

Comment: @EdsonReis Discordo de ser duplicata. Nesta pergunta, o usuário quer saber qual é o melhor para fazer um menu. Na outra, nada se fala acerca de menu.

Answer (score 8):

## Estratégias esotéricas

A [resposta do @Ruy Neto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/241669/64969) trata do principal. Mas a pergunta não se limita a resoluções práticas, lembra mais um exercício. Já que é um exercício, vamos exercitar?

### `goto`

```
int main() {
  int op;

  goto INICIO;

SAIDA:
  saudacoes_tchau();

  return 0;
INICIO:
  saudacoes_oi();
VOLTA:

  op = le_operacao();
  trata_operacao(op);
  if (op) {
    goto VOLTA;
  } else {
    goto SAIDA;
  }

}
```

O `goto` vai forçar um salto incondicional para algum lugar apontado no código<sup>1</sup>. No caso, para `VOLTA`, o comando logo depois de `saudacoes_oi()`

---

<sup>1: no caso do C, e em algumas outras linguagens que dão suporte ao `goto`, o "lugar apontado no código" não é totalmente arbitrário; ele precisa ser dentro da mesma função. Se não me engano, em Pascal, o `goto` podia ir para qualquer ponto arbitrário no sistema, deixando o fluxo do código mais macarrônico do que o "normal"; felizmente C não permite isso, tem a restrição de estar na mesma função</sup>

---

### Recursão direta da função, condição de cauda

```
void funcao_menu() {
  int op;
  op = le_operacao();
  trata_operacao(op);

  if (op) {
    funcao_menu();
  }
}

int main() {
  saudacoes_oi();
  funcao_menu();
  saudacoes_tchau();
  return 0;
}
```

Chamando recursivamente a função para tratar as operações disponíveis no menu. Note que aqui eu sempre executo a função inteira para, então escolher se devo fazer a chamada, na cauda, da função.

### Recursão indireta da função, ponteiro de função

```
void funcao_menu() {
  void (*proxima_chamada)();
  int op;

  proxima_chamada = &saudacoes_tchau;
  op = le_operacao();
  trata_operacao(op);

  if (op) {
    proxima_chamada = &funcao_menu;
  }
  (*proxima_chamada)();
}

int main() {
  saudacoes_oi();
  funcao_menu();

  return 0;
}
```

Agora, a escolha é feita entre chamar o `tchau` ou a função propriamente dita.

### Recursão direta da função, condição no argumento

```
void funcao_menu(int old_op) {
  int op;
  if (old_op) {
    op = le_operacao();
    trata_operacao(op);

    funcao_menu(op);
  }
}

int main() {
  saudacoes_oi();
  funcao_menu(1);
  saudacoes_tchau();
  return 0;
}
```

Aqui, quem define se haverá recursão ou não é o parâmetro da função. Se for passado um argumento verdadeiro, ela é executada; caso contrário, fecha o laço.

### Recursão indireta a função, funções mutuamente recursivas

```
void funcao_menu();

void trata_operacao_chama_funcao_menu(int op) {
  if (op) {
    trata_operacao(op);
    funcao_menu();
  }
}

void funcao_menu() {
  trata_operacao_chama_funcao_menu(le_operacao());
}

int main() {
  saudacoes_oi();
  funcao_menu();
  saudacoes_tchau();
  return 0;
}
```

`trata_operacao_chama_funcao_menu` chama `funcao_menu` que chama `trata_operacao_chama_funcao_menu`.

### Recursão usando chamadas de sistema

Para essa, eu vou remover a saudação do `oi`, porque é difícil definir quando ela deve ser feita.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int op = le_operacao();

  if (op) {
    trata_operacao(op);
    return system(argv[0]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Olá, você pode usar qualquer laço de repetição para fazer um loop infinito, segue 3 exemplos:

1 - Com for.

```
for(;;){
//comandos
}
```

2 - Com while.

```
while(true){
//comandos
}
```

3 - Com do while.

```
do{
//comandos
}while(true);
```

Para sair do laço, use o seguinte comando com uma condicional:

```
break;
```

Comment: Faltou com `goto` e com recursão

Comment: Por isso que eu disse 3 exemplos, caro colega.

Comment: então vou escrever métodos mais esotéricos para laços de repetição

Comment: Por favor, o faça.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica !!

Comment: no break tem que colocar uma condição também?

Comment: Poderia mandar o código para dar uma olhada e me ajudar ?

Comment: Algumas partes não estão funcionando

Comment: O break; para um loop na hora que é executável, é comum você usar uma condicional para executa-lo.

Exemplo: leia infinitos nomes até o usuário digitar "#", você vai precisar de um break junto com uma condicional.

Comment: Poste suas dúvidas no site para outras pessoas verem e te ajudar, não obrigatoriamente sendo eu ou não.

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso, o ideal é usar o do-while pois vocês quer mostrar o menu antes de pedir a opção do usuário:

```
int opcao = 0;

do {
   printf("\n0 - SAIR");
   printf("\n1 - Op 1");
   ...
   scanf("%d", &opcao);
} while (opcao != 0);
```