# Loops com base em um fluxograma

Tags: java, loop, do-while, java-processing

Como faço para escrever o código para um loop com base nesse fluxograma? Tem um `do...while`. Peeciso de uma resposta simples e direta com nested loops.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Java ou Processing ? A sua dúvida é em relação ao fluxograma ou ao `do...while` ? Independentemente disso aconselho a rever toda a matéria dada pelo professor

Comment: Processing ou java. O importante é eu entender como interpretar o fluxograma. Na matéria não ficou claro. Queria chegar nos 5 loops, mas não estou conseguindo sair nem do primeiro.

Comment: Isso eu faria com um loop infinito e um `break` em `B`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado pode me dar um exemplo?

Comment: Estou providenciando na resposta ;-)

Comment: São 5 possíveis formar de escrever esse loop. Essa seria uma? `int i=0;
do {
  println("A");
} while (i<5);

while(i<5){
  println ("C");  
}`

Comment: @Jsi83 A resposta dada responde, sim, a sua pergunta. Se não entendeu alguma coisa, sinta-se livre para questionar o autor nos comentários. A edição recente que você fez na pergunta altera, mesmo que levemente, o sentido da pergunta. Você inicialmente pediu exemplos de laços de repetição que seguem o fluxograma - cinco, para ser exato. O Jefferson mostrou muito mais que isso. Se realmente a resposta não é a desejada, você precisa rever seu texto, pois o que você pediu ele respondeu.

Comment: Eu mudei a pergunta, pois a resposta não usa do...while, e isso faz com que "A" não seja executado nenhuma vez se a condição é falsa . Assim, não corresponde ao fluxograma.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esse fluxo, me diz o seguinte:

1. Execute tarefa `A`
2. Faça a comparação `B`; se der verdadeiro, saia do laço
3. Execute a tarefa `C`
4. Volte para o passo 1

Note que o fluxo no passo 4 é um desvio incondicional retornando para o passo 1. Esse desvio acaba por criar um laço infinito (enquanto `B` não for satisfeito). De modo geral, eu faria assim:

```
while (true) {
  // passo 1
  // passo 2
  // passo 3
}
```

O passo 4 está representado pelo controle de fluxo fornecido pelo `while`. Preenchendo algumas lacunas a mais, obtemos:

```
while (true) {
  A();
  // passo 2
  C();
}
```

Assumindo que `A()` e `C()` são os métodos chamados nos passos 1 e 3. Pode ser qualquer coisa, mas representei por métodos.

Sobre o passo 2, ele envolve uma condicional em `B`. Não tem caso `senão`. Então, de modo geral:

```
while (true) {
  A();
  if (B()) {
    // ação caso B seja verdadeiro
  }
  C();
}
```

A ação para sair do laço é com o `break`. Então:

```
while (true) {
  A();
  if (B()) {
    break;
  }
  C();
}
```

---

> Usando a linguagem `dot` para descrever seu diagrama, obtive o seguinte:
>
> [image: diagrama original, mas em dot]
>
> Estou só republicando-a aqui pois vou usar essa linguagem para fazer algumas manipulações na estrutura do laço e gerar outras equivalentes, então a ideia é diminuir o estranhamento.

A estrutura do laço é equivalente à expressão:

```
AB(CAB)*
```

Por que falo isso? Simples, porque inicialmente `A` e `B` são executados e, dependendo desse resultado, executo `C`, depois `A` (voltando no laço) e então `B` novamente, para tomar a decisão para onde partir.

A seguinte descrição é a tradução da expressão. Note que esse passo-a-passo é equivalente ao primeiro.

1. Execute tarefa `A`
2. Enquanto não `B`, faça:

   1. Execute `C`
   2. Execute `A`

Comparando com o esquema anterior, não precisei mais de um passo de desvio incondicional, usei um "enquanto". Copiei o comando que estava anterior à condicional para o final do laço, de modo que seja executado na hora certa a mesma quantidade de vezes.

O fluxograma agora é desenhado assim:

[image: A1-> B -> C -> A2 -> B...]

Em código, o **enquanto** vira um `while`. O resto se mantém:

```
A();
while (!B()) { // perceba que eu só repito enquanto `B()` for falso, já que `B()` é a condição de saída
  C();
  A();
}
```

---

Ainda usando o fluxograma 2, podemos fazer usando o `for`. Não gosto dessa alternativa, mas ela funciona.

```
A();
for (; !B(); A()) {
  C();
}
```

---

Alterando um pouco o `for`, obtemos o seguinte:

```
A();
for (; !B(); C(), A());
```

---

Podemos fazer o `for` como laço infinito também:

```
for (;;C()) {
  A();
  if (B()) {
    break;
  }
}
```

---

Se fizer muita insistência em fazer a verificação depois das operações, essa operação precisa ficar necessariamente depois de todas as operações. Para isso, podemos definir que o *rodável* inicial seja apenas `A`, atribuir para o *rodável* a executação de `C` e em seguida `A` e, então, fazer a verificação condicional:

```
Runnable rodavel = () -> { A(); };
do {
  rodavel.run();
  rodavel = () -> { C(); A(); };
} while (!B());
```

---

Podemos também controlar de outra maneira o jeito como se roda a operação `C`. Podemos controlar através de uma *flag* mnemonicamente denominada `deveExecutarC`, que começa como falsa mas, no final do laço, é atribuído o valor verdadeiro nela:

```
boolean deveExecutarC = false;
do {
  if (deveExecutarC) {
    C();
  }
  A();
  deveExecutarC = true;
} while (!B());
```

---

Podemos tentar atribuir diversas vezes o valor da flag ao colocar essa atribuição dentro do bloco `else`:

```
boolean deveExecutarC = false;
do {
  if (deveExecutarC) {
    C();
  } else {
    deveExecutarC = true;
  }
  A();
} while (!B());
```

---

Esse problema poderia ser resolvido recursivamente também:

```
private void executaRecursivo() {
  C();
  A();
  if (!B()) {
    executaRecursivo();
  }
}

private void fluxograma() {
  A();
  if (!B()) {
    executaResursivo();
  }
}
```

Basta chamar o método `fluxograma` e você obterá a mesma execução.

---

Podemos pôr a recursão de modo distinto, passando um parâmetro para ela. A ideia é a mesmo do `do-while` com a flag `deveExecutarC`:

```
private void fluxograma(boolean deveExecutarC) {
  if (deveExecutarC) {
    C();
  }
  A();
  if (!B()) {
    fluxograma(true);
  }
}

private void fluxograma() {
  fluxograma(false);
}
```

Para obter o resultado desejado, basta chamar `fluxograma()`, sem argumentos.

---

Mais variação com recursão:

```
private void recursao() {
  if (!B()) {
    C();
    A();
    recursao();
  }
}

private void fluxograma() {
  A();
  recursao();
}
```

Como de costume, basta chamar `fluxograma()`.

---

Uma variação mais amigável da recursão anterior:

```
private void recursao() {
  if (B()) {
    return;
  }
  C();
  A();
  recursao();
}

private void fluxograma() {
  A();
  recursao();
}
```

Como de costume, basta chamar `fluxograma()`.

---

Outra variação:

```
private void fluxograma() {
  A();
  if (B()) {
    return;
  }
  C();
  fluxograma();
}
```

Como de costume, basta chamar `fluxograma()`.

---

Mais uma recursão, inspirada [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/241694/64969), desdobramento **Recursão indireta da função, ponteiro de função**:

```
private void fluxograma() {
  A();
  Runnable funcaoSaida = B()? () -> {}: () -> { C(); fluxograma(); };
  funcaoSaida.run();
}
```

Como de costume, basta chamar `fluxograma()`.

---

Se não desejar a variável:

```
private void fluxograma() {
  A();
  (B()? (Runnable) () -> {}: (Runnable) () -> { C(); fluxograma(); }).run();
}
```

Como de costume, basta chamar `fluxograma()`.

Comment: Entendi o que tu fez e acho que é a melehor solução. Mas, e os outros 4 loops? Tenho que usar um loop dentro de outro?

Comment: Estou trabalhando para mostrar como manipular a ordem das operações, de modo a obter fluxos equivalentes e, portanto, um outro modo de ordenar. Só por curiosidade, de onde tirou esse número 5?

Comment: O número 5 é qualquer número. Estou tentando gerar o mesmo resultado para esses loops. Poderia ser qualquer número. Somente criei uma condição.

Comment: Então não são "5 formas possíveis de escrever". Você está a descrever um laço que se repita 5 vezes

Comment: Não, o 5 era um teste e poderia ser qualquer coisa. Fiz um código sem sentido. São 5 diferentes respostas para o fluxograma. Um loop é com break (resposta 1), o outro acredito que seja loops alinhados (resposta 2), o outro um loop fora do outro (resposta 3), mas e os outros 2?

Comment: Vendo as respostas [dessa questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241665/64969) eu consegui contar pelo menos 7 maneiras para o seu caso

Comment: Tu poderias me ajudar a escrever o loop sem o break? no fluxograma tem um do...while com certeza, pois A vem antes da condicão. Até aí tudo bem, mas como dou continuidade ao loop com o C? é metade e metade: A precisa ser executado ando da condicão e C, não.

Comment: 15 alternativas: 2 com `while`, 3 com `for`, 3 com `do-while`, e o restante com recursões esotéricas. Cansei de variar, poderia ir longe ainda. Bons estudos

Comment: A resposta dada parece muito complexa. Eu só preciso de um do..while que represente o fluxograma.

Comment: Eu te dei 3 opções com `do-while` de maneira que você pode se servir delas a vontade. Inclusive mostrei fluxos de equivalência e também o comportamento regular esperado desse esquema algorítmico.

Comment: Eu estou começando a entender loops. Ficou ainda mais complicado. "A' deve ser executado pelo menos uma vez. Se uso while sem o do, isso não ocorre.

Comment: Eu dei duas opções com `while` que trivialmente você verifica que `A()` é executado sempre

Comment: O que não ficou claro: o losango é uma condição representada no fluxograma, ele é  um IF ou um WHILE no código?

Comment: @Jsi83 `while`, `if` e `for` tem condicionais dentro deles. Esse losango e esses quadrados tem uma visão mais parecida com montagem do que com estruturada ou orientada a objetos. Entenda que isso é uma máquina de estados, em que, dado um estado, é necessário ir para outro. Não tente pegar um dicionário e traduzir literalmente isso que está escrito. Para traduzir literalmente, você necessitaria de `goto`, mas Java não tem isso

Comment: `do{ A if (true) break; C } while(true);` Esse codigo faz sentido pra ti?

Comment: Não tem `B`, portanto não atende à pergunta. Sem falar que do jeito que está escrito, a versão correta é a mesma coisa da primeira opção que eu fiz, com `while`

Comment: `do {
  A();
  if (B()) {
    break;
  }
  C();
}while (true)` Posso inverter o while e usar do?

Comment: Note que isso é idêntico à primeira forma que eu escrevi.

Comment: Então agora acho entendi. Essa é uma forma de escrever o loop. Agora falta eu entender as outras 4 formas.

Comment: Eu lhe fornece 15