# Calculadora em C (Iniciante)

Tags: c

Estou com uma dúvida no seguinte exercício:

> Elabore um programa que receba dois números inteiros e mostre o
>   resultado da divisão dos números e seu resto. o programa devera
>   perguntar se o usuário pretende repetir a operação ou encerrar o
>   programa.

Não sei como fazer para que no final do programa se eu digitar 1, ele encerre, se digitar 2 recomece, segue abaixo meu programa:

```
int main() 
{   
    int var1, var2, Q, R;
    printf("Digite o dividendo: ");
    scanf("%d", &var1);
    printf("Digite o divisor: ");
    scanf("%d", &var2);
    Q = var1 / var2;
    R = var1 % var2;
    printf("Resultado: %d\n", Q);
    printf("Resto: %d\n", R);

    int decisao;
    printf("\nDeseja encerrar o programa? \n1 para sim e 2 para nao.");
    scanf("%d", &decisao);
}
```

Comment: Já estudou o comando `while`? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/241665/la%C3%A7o-de-repeti%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-c/241694

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar um laço de repetição ou ao final do seu código, você pode adicionar um `if` para verificar se o valor contido na variável decisão é igual a dois, se o resultado da comparação for verdadeiro então você pode chamar o método `main()` novamente.

Exemplo com laço `Do While`:

```
int main() 
{   
    int var1, var2, Q, R, decisao = 2;

    do {
        printf("Digite o dividendo: ");
        scanf("%d", &var1);
        printf("Digite o divisor: ");
        scanf("%d", &var2);
        Q = var1 / var2;
        R = var1 % var2;
        printf("Resultado: %d\n", Q);
        printf("Resto: %d\n", R);

        printf("\n Caso deseje repetir a operacao digite 2 ou digite qualquer outro valor para encerrar.\n");
        scanf("%d", &decisao);

    } while(decisao == 2);

}
```

Exemplo com recursão:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{   
    int var1, var2, Q, R;
    printf("Digite o dividendo: ");
    scanf("%d", &var1);
    printf("Digite o divisor: ");
    scanf("%d", &var2);
    Q = var1 / var2;
    R = var1 % var2;
    printf("Resultado: %d\n", Q);
    printf("Resto: %d\n", R);

    int decisao;
    printf("\n Caso deseje repetir a operacao digite 2 ou digite qualquer outro valor para encerrar.\n");
    scanf("%d", &decisao);

    if(decisao == 2)
        return main();  

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observação, eu mudei a mensagem pois o programa encerrará para qualquer valor diferente de dois.

Comment: Nota ao leitor: Recursão da função `main` não é a coisa mais comum de se encontrar por aí. Normalmente é algo que se evita.