# Dúvidas sobre looping em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loop

Eu reparei que é muito usado `var i` e quando é `for`/`in` e `var x`, por que usar essas letras?

Eu posso usar palavras no lugar delas e vai funcionar normalmente.

Eu posso colocar um `for` dentro de outro? Isso causaria algum problema?

Quando `while` deve ser usado e qual a diferença entre `while` e `do/while`?

Estava tentando entender um pouco sobre isso lendo no [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp), mas não está muito claro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tem um padrão e nunca notei essa variação de `i` para `x` por causa disso, há quem goste de `i` (eu), há quem goste de `x` (acho que é para outra coisa), e claro há quem deve ter adotado o padrão de uma em um tipo de *loop* e outra no outro tipo. Não vejo motivo pra isso, quem o faz é que deveria explicar porque o faz, mas eu já chuto que é apenas gosto.

Pode usar o que quiser, há apenas uma convenção de usar uma letra simples porque em geral ela só está ali por causa do mecanismo de *looping* e não faz parte do domínio do problema, então é até uma forma de diferenciar e evitar enfatizar sua presença. Pode usar `contador` como alguns o fazem, acham horrível e vejo como uma diminuição da legibilidade, trazendo verbosidade para algo que não importa.

Melhor ainda quando pode usar uma construção de laço que não precisa de uma variável de controle e ela já estabelece uma variável para o item sendo analisado naquele passo.

Você pode fazer um `for` dentro do outro e pode usar `i`, `j`, `k`, `l` (ainda que ela possa ser confundida com 1 (um), ou outras letras. Em alguns cenários pode ser que o `x`, `y`, `w`, `z` sejam mais adequados, se estiver falando de eixos, assim como há casos para uso de `m`e `n`, ou ainda `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, mas são mais raros. `i` e `j` são disparados os mais comuns em códigos. "Todo mundo" sabe o que é.

O único problema de um `for` dentro do outro é que você passa ter um algoritmo exponencial (complexidade representado por O(N<sup>2</sup>)) e isto não é muito desejável, mas não é tão trágico e há casos que é a única forma de fazê-lo. E se for em baixos volumes não deve fazer tanta diferença. Só certifique-se que precisa mesmo fazer desta forma.

Sobre o `while` já foi respondida: [Qual a diferença entre o while, for, do while e foreach?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157512/101) e [Qual é a utilidade e importância de "do... while"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78493/101). Não sei se ainda é verdade, mas dizem que W3Scools não é uma boa fonte.

Comment: Falando por mim apenas, eu uso i apenas por que onde aprendi estava escrito i, e na maioria dos lugares também. Acredito que se use o i por estar meio que no meio do alfabeto, e já que é comum se utilizar ou 'a, b, c' ou 'x, y, z', foi feita alguma convenção a muito tempo atrás de se usar o i, j, k para loops não conflitando com outras variáveis que venham a aparecer. Mas isso é só um chute.

Comment: Eu acho, e só acho, que `i´ é de *index*. Aí foi natural continuar. Acho que vem da matemática mesmo. Em geral são as únicas variáveis de uma letra só que deveriam ter no código, salvo se realmente algo significativo tenha só uma letra.