# Ao compilar o código, tanto o numero1 quanto o numero2 exibem o mesmo valor mesmo tendo um incremento

Tags: java, operadores

```
public class IncrementoDecremento{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer numero1 = 10;
        Integer numero2 = ++numero1;

        System.out.println("numero: " + numero1 + ", numero2: " + numero2);


    }

}
```

Como funciona esse Incremento?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É simplesmente uma questão de onde esta o `++`

```
Integer numero2 = ++numero1;
```

Isso se transforma nisso:

```
numero1 = numero1 + 1;
Integer numero2 = numero1;
```

Agora se você colocar:

```
Integer numero2 = numero1++;
```

Vira isso:

```
Interger numero2 = numero1;
numero1 = numero1 + 1;
```

Comment: A explicação mais simples foi a que me fez entender. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 8):

Ele é chamado pré incremento então ele pega o valor da variável em que ele opera e muda seu valor adicionando 1 ao que já existia. E como o operador resulta em uma expressão o resultado disso pode ser usado em qualquer lugar que espera uma expressão, então nesse exemplo esse novo valor é atribuído para a nova variável.

O compilador acabará fazendo o mesmo que este código:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer numero1 = 10;
        numero1++;
        Integer numero2 = numero1;
        System.out.println("numero: " + numero1 + ", numero2: " + numero2);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/MhGWv7). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/PostIncrementjava). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Operator/PostIncrement.java).

Isso é diferente do pós incremento em que o valor da variável é usado na expressão antes de aplicar a operação, então o valor de `numero1` acabaria sendo o mesmo, mas `numero2` daria um resultado diferente. Que ficaria assim:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer numero1 = 10;
        Integer numero2 = numero1;
        numero1++;
        System.out.println("numero: " + numero1 + ", numero2: " + numero2);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Tv1m3P). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/PreIncrementjava). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Operator/PreIncrement.java).

A recomendação é não usar operações que causa [efeito colateral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/330341/101) (muda o estado) em um lugar que espera uma expressão, então toda vez que o operador faz uma atribuição na própria variável faça isso em uma linha separada. Outra forma é usar parenteses para conter a expressão, mas na prática isso transformaria até o pós incremento em pré incremento, o que pode não ser o desejado, então só evite por tudo na mesma linha dois operadores que fazem atribuição.

Também não é muito interessante o uso do tipo `Integer` (é uma pena até que ele exista), prefira o `int` sempre que possível.