# Pós-incremento, pré-incremento e sua precedência

Tags: java, operadores

[image: tabela de precedÊncia e operadores]

Nos dois casos seguindo a precedência da tabela acima ficariam assim:

## Caso 1

```
int x = 3;
int y = ++x * 5 / x-- + --x;
```

Baseado na tabela de precedência o pós-unário não viria a frente do pré incremento?

```
 3 * 5 / 3 + 2
  15 / 3 + 2
   5 + 2 = 7
```

Porém conforme a resposta do guia oficial seria essa:

```
  4 * 5 / 4 + 2
    5 + 2 = 7
```

Apesar da resposta final igual, qual seria a explicação para não ter usado a precedência?

## Caso 2

```
int i = 5
int j = i++ * ++i + 20;


 5 * 7 + 20

35 + 20 = 55
```

*saída: 55, aqui entendi o porque*

Mas se fizermos:

```
int i = 5;
int j = ++i * i++ + 20;
```

```
 7 * 5 + 20

35 + 20 = 55
```

Porém a saída no IDE é 56. Poderia me explicar por que do resultado 56?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O primeiro caso é um pouco mais complicado porque a gente não está vendo o valor de `x´, eu posso inferir que seja 3.

Então ele faz um pré-incremento e o valor de `x` vira 4. Depois ele faz um pós-descremento, portanto ele pega o mesmo valor que já tem e logo depois subtrai 1 fazendo `x` valor 3. Em por último, ele fa um pré-decremento, pegando o valor 3 e mudando para 2 que é o valor usado.

O segundo caso na sua explicação está errado, seria:

```
6 * 6 + 20

36 + 20 = 56
```

O pré-incremento ocorre. Então o valor de `i` que era 5 passa ser 6, portanto é esse valor que será usado. Depois o mesmo valor 6 é usado novamente. Depois que ele for usado `i` passa valer 7, mas como é um pós-incremento essa mudança só ocorrerá depois após o valor já ser usado.

Quando faz o pré o valor é modificado na variável e então esse novo valor é usado onde a variável está na expressão. Quando faz o pós, o valor da variável é usado no local da expressão onde ela está, e depois que já foi usado o valor da variável é mudado, portanto só no próximo uso da variável é que o valor será visto mudado.

Mas é muito simples resolver tudo isso em código real. Jamais use um operador que provoca [efeito colateral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/330341/101) junto com outros operadores. Use-os sozinhos em uma linha ou então em algum lugar que o resultado será usado diretamente sem ser parte de uma expressão maior.

Algumas linguagens até acabaram com esses operadores porque as pessoas faziam essas coisas confusas. Faça assim que nunca dá dor de cabeça:

```
i++;
metodo(++i);
array[i++];
```

Algumas pessoas acham que deve usar só o primeiro, os outros dois as pessoas já não entendem bem o que acontece. O primeiro não importa, vai fazer o que se espera de forma fácil de entender.

Até isto não é um problema tão grande, mas já gera alguma confusão:

```
x++ * 2
```

Note que a variável que sofreu mutação foi usada só uma vez.

Portanto ele usou a precedência, você não usou. O não uso da precedência seria ele, por exemplo, fazer a multiplicação antes de fazer o incremento. Ele fez isto:

```
int y = ((((++x) * 5) / (x--)) + (--x));
```

Tabela de precedência com associatividade:

[image: Tabela de precedência com associatividade]

A precedência só faz sentido olhando em pares, não a expressão toda. Não é que você olha tudo e escolhe qual vai primeiro, tem que ir olhando parte por parte. Por exemplo:

```
int y = ++x * 5 / x-- + --x;
```

O primeiro operador que encontramos é o de atribuição, o `=`. Ele tem precedência baixa, portanto deve olhar tudo o que está à esquerda e à direita primeiro para depois usá-lo. Não que essa sintaxe funcione, mas seria mais ou menos isto:

```
(int y) = (++x * 5 / x-- + --x);
```

Ele acabará ficando em último por causa da precedência muito baixa.

Quando o compilador estabelece precedência e associatividade no fundo o que ele faz é colocar parênteses nos lugares corretos de acordo com as regras estabelecidas.

Continuando, agora temos:

```
++ x * 5
```

O que ele deve fazer primeiro? O compilador pega as regras e determina que será assim:

```
(++x) * 5
```

Agora temos:

```
(++x) * 5 / x
```

Ele deve fazer primeiro a multiplicação ou divisão? Ambos operadores tem a mesma precedência. A associatividade é da esquerda para a direita então primeiro faz a multiplicação:

```
((++x) * 5) / x
```

Continuando:

```
((++x) * 5) / x--
```

Agora entre a divisão e o pós incremento quem ganha é o segundo porque ele tem precedência maior, fica assim:

```
((++x) * 5) / (x--)
```

Continuando:

```
((++x) * 5) / (x--) + --x
```

Novamente o pré decemento ganaha e fica:

```
((++x) * 5) / (x--) + (--x)
```

Agora como resolver entre a divisão e a adição?

```
(((++x) * 5) / (x--)) + (--x)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Operator/Precedence.java).

A divisão tem precedência sobre a adição então ficou desse jeito.

Por último tudo isso está entre parênteses para aplicar com o `=` que tem a menor precedência. Agora fica fácil visualizar, resolvemos tudo da esquerda para a direita apenas respeitando os parênteses. Faz o pré incremento, depois multiplica esse resultado com o literal 5, depois faz a divisão desse resultado com o resultado do pós decremento (porque eles está entre parênteses). depois pega todo esse resultado e adiciona como o resultado do pré incremento.

Se a linguagem não tivesse precedência (eu já bolei uma linguagem assim experimentalmente só para ver como fica) para dar o mesmo resultado você teria que que por todos esses parênteses na mão.

Comment: No caso como x++ está acima de ++x na tabela de precedência achei que fizesse sempre primeiro o pós incremento (ou pós decremento) sempre. Entao a precedência para esses casos vai ser sempre da esquerda para direita?

Comment: A precedência se dá sempre entre dois operadores quando há ambiguidade de qual deve vir primeiro, não afeta a expressão toda. Vale pra tudo, sempre olha um operador com o do lado para decidir qual vem primeiro, não olha os demais, aí olha pra outros 2, que um deles pode ser que já resolveu antes.

Comment: Por favor pode me explicar mais sobre essa tabela nao consegui compreender, to ficando com mais duvidas rsrs
 int i = 5; int j = 5;

  System.out.println(j + 1 / i++ - i--);

Saída: -1


saída: -1

Comment: Ela mostra quando como o operador deve ser lido quando vai desambiguar qual vai primeiro, se olha do jeito que estamos acostumados da esquerda para a direita, ou o oposto. Por exemplo um operador de atribuição, isso é importante quando os operadores possuem a mesma precedência.