# Incremento não funciona como esperado

Tags: c, ponteiro

Peguei esse exercício e coloquei pra compilar, mas esta dando errado eu acho pois os valores que eu vejo seriam 5 e 9, porem esta dando 6 e 8, acredito que a IDE não esteja lendo corretamente.

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main (){
 int i = 5, j = 3, *p, *q;
 p = &i;
 q = &j;
 printf("%d %d \n", *p, (*p)++ + *q);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: "*acredito que a IDE nao esteja lendo corretamente*" - Vc não disse qual IDE está usando, mas a menos que seja uma meio desconhecida, é improvável que o problema seja dela. IDE's são usadas há décadas por milhões de profissionais no mundo todo, para fazer programas complexos e diversos, então qual a chance de você, fazendo um exercício simples, ter encontrado um problema grave em uma funcionalidade tão básica? Não estou dizendo que é impossível, mas é **extremamente improvável**. "Nunca" (ou "quase nunca") a culpa é da IDE, do compilador ou da linguagem. Quase sempre a culpa é do programador.

Comment: Enfim, como é um comportamento indefinido, o resultado pode variar de acordo com o compilador. Só pra citar 2 exemplos, no IdeOne.com (usando gcc 8.3) [o resultado foi `6 8`](https://ideone.com/aaYM6H) e no Repl.it (usando clang-7) [o resultado foi `5 8`](https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/BlaringFlimsyQuote#main.c). E se a faculdade diz que a resposta é "sempre `x y`", questione e pergunte porque ninguém explicou que isso é comportamento indefinido...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, precisa ler [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101).

Se você acha que deveria dar outro valor deveria justificar isso. Programação é justificativa, caso contrário vira sandice.

Você pegou um [comportamento indefinido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/101). Portanto não faça isso, não tem necessidade. Tem compilador que nem deixa compilar isso se não forçar. Não use operadores que possuem [efeitos colaterais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/330341/101), como é o caso do incremento (`++`) junto com outras expressões, tudo pode acontecer sem que o código esteja errado, e portanto você não tem controle sobre isso. Se quer mesmo fazer o incremento então o faça em uma linha separada e controle o momento exato que deveria acontecer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    int i = 5, j = 3, *p = &i, *q = &j, x = (*p)++;
    printf("%d %d \n", *p, x + *q);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/tRxg5H). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/yffnpyie-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Operator/UndefinedBehavior.c).

Assim você tem controle e dá o resultado que obteve, ou seja, o compilador escolheu fazer primeiro o incremento e depois fazer o resto, que é o que eu faria já que o operador de incremento tem precedência sobre os demais, inclusive a vírgula que tem menos precedência, então ele é executado antes de tudo e depois usa o resultado já obtido. Embora o resultado que espera poderia ser conseguido em algum compilador ou plataforma, ele faria menos sentido.

Na verdade 5 e 9 eu nem consigo imaginar porque daria, você deveria realmente justificar isso.

E não pode mudar qualquer coisa no código, achar que ficou parecido e então dar o resultado esperado, outro código é outro código. UM código que não tem efeito colateral vai dar resultado diferente, são operações completamente distintas.

Comment: Interessante os textos, eu não sei direito sobre ponteiros estou aprendendo na faculdade, isso é um exercício dela para falar qual o valor daria, não sabia que tinha problemas como o que vc disse, mas obrigado pelas instruções Manieri

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main (){
 int i = 5, j = 3, *p, *q;
 p = &i;
 q = &j;

 printf("%d %d \n", *p,(*p + 1 + *q ));
    return 0;
    }
```

Fiz dessa forma, e saiu o que você queria ... é uma forma meio esquisita, mas foi

Comment: cara o codigo é o mesmo quase, pelo menos na parte que o seu da 5, por que sera que acontece isso

Comment: @Cl2727 Porque - como já explicou a outra resposta - uma expressão que tem o operador `++` junto com outras operações gera comportamento indefinido. Removendo o `++`, o comportamento indefinido some, já que agora o valor de `*p` não é mais alterado durante a avaliação da expressão.

Comment: entendi, valeu hkotsubo!!